# how to edit attachments?

Tags: posts, attachments

when attaching eg. files to a post, how can i edit/delete them afterwards?
couldn't find anything in the post editor.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Media Uploader.

1. Press Upload Photo above the editor.
2. See the tab "Gallery( number-of-items-attacched )"
3. Manage / Rerrange order
4. To delete: show an item and press Delete (it's at below of the window)